# Obtaining phone number from lookup URI

Tags: android, uri, android-contacts, android-cursor

I've been trying to obtain a contact's phone number using their lookup URI, but I'm not getting it to work.

```
Cursor myC = getContentResolver().query(lookupURI, null, null,
                        null, null);
                String phoneNumber;
                if (myC.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (myC.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = myC.getString(myC
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        Log.v("t", "phone number is: " + phoneNumber);
                    }
                }
```

where `lookupURI.toString()` is this URI: `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r1-304846522C3052482C4A3442423C3248/1`

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Can't guarantee this'll work for 4.0 because I haven't used it in a while but works fine on 2.3.3:

To get the contactId, I first get the user to select a contact:

```
public void clickSelectContact(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

When the user has selected a contact it comes back to this method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == CONTACTS_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
             Uri uri = data.getData();
             System.out.println("uri: "+uri);
             System.out.println("PHONE NUMBER: " +  PhoneUtils.getContactPhoneNumber(this, uri.getLastPathSegment()));
        }
    }
}
```

Which calls my static util class:

```
private static final String TAG = "PhoneUtils";

public static String getContactPhoneNumber(Context context, String contactId) {
   int type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
   String phoneNumber = null;

   String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId), String.valueOf(type) };

   Log.d(TAG, "Got contact id: "+contactId);

   Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ? and " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = ?", 
                            whereArgs, 
                            null);

  int phoneNumberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

  if (cursor != null) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Returned contact count: "+cursor.getCount());
       try {
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIndex);
             }
            } finally {
               cursor.close();
            }
   }

  Log.d(TAG, "Returning phone number: "+phoneNumber);
  return phoneNumber;
}
```

Where contactId = lookupURI.getLastPathSegment();

So complex for such a simple thing! :-(

P.s. you may need this permission in your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```