# Android Contact phone number using Loader Invalid column data1

Tags: android, contacts

I used to use content resolver previously to fetch Contact list and their details while that still works I wanted to try the Loader method which queries the Content Provider in the background. I have looked at the documentation and sample code here :

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html

While I was able to display a list of Contacts without any problems, I am stuck at retrieving Phone Number of a particular contact on clicking it and showing it on a detail screen. The demo above shows address of the user on the detail screen, I even tried modifying it. I have changed the content URI from Contacts to ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone but I keep getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
```

There is not a single detailed tutorial on the internet showing how it is done. Can someone here be kind enough to shed some light? Reading various other Stackoverflow questions I am oretty sure it has something to do with the 2 different CONTENT URI but again I could be wrong. Any help or pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks

Few of the SO Questions I have already looked at :

[Get phone number from contact loader in android: projection crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665392/get-phone-number-from-contact-loader-in-android-projection-crash)

[Logcat says "invalid column data1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255434/logcat-says-invalid-column-data1)

[How to get contacts' phone number in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218845/how-to-get-contacts-phone-number-in-android)

[Obtaining phone number from lookup URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594987/obtaining-phone-number-from-lookup-uri)

None of them solve my problem. Here is the relevant code where it fails :

```
     final static String[] PROJECTION = {
            Contacts._ID,
            Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
           //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
    };
```

The code works just fine, but the moment I remove the comment to fetch Phone Number it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excerpt of what I actually do in my (working) code.

These are my relevant imports:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
```

Given that id is a string (representing a number, like "1", "20", ...)

```
// Query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
final Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query
    (
    Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
    Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
    new String[] {id}, null
    );

final int phoneIdx = cur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
final int phoneType = cur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

// ...

    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        final String name =
            cur.getString
            (
                cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                (
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                )
            );
    }
```

Hope it puts you on the right path

Answer (score 9):

In my case the problem was with **URI**.

I was using this:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
```

and I changed for this (**Phone.CONTENT_URI**) to resolve the problem and obtain the phone number:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
contactos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactos);

Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

String [] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String telefono = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contactos.append("Name: ");
            contactos.append(nombre);
            contactos.append(" - Phone Number: ");
            contactos.append(telefono);
            contactos.append("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Casariedo Thank you, this saved me lot of time !

Answer (score 1):

### Change Your Query URI.

You are using a URI that is not meant for searching/filtering those columns (e.g. phone numbers) on Contacts:

You need to use a URI that has access to the columns you're trying to filter on, like this:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
```

Or maybe this one since you're searching phone numbers:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI;
```

There's a decent breakdown of what URIs to use and when on the [Android SDK Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts):

> - If you need to read an individual contact, consider using CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI instead of CONTENT_URI.
> - If you need to look up a contact by the phone number, use PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, which is optimized for this purpose.
> - If you need to look up a contact by partial name, e.g. to produce filter-as-you-type suggestions, use the CONTENT_FILTER_URI URI.
> - If you need to look up a contact by some data element like email address, nickname, etc, use a query against the ContactsContract.Data table. The result will contain contact ID, name etc.